# How to get $.ajax raw request response text

Tags: xml, jquery, jsonp

I use `$.ajax` to get a cross domain xml data, by setting the `datatype` to `jsonp`.

Good news is I can get the data correctly, through check the HttpRequest response data.Bad news is the xml I get can not be print or parse by the ajax function, so it report me wrong, the data was intercepted.

So I thought whether I can get the raw response text before the `$.ajax` parse and intercept it, then I can parse the text by myself.

Is that possible? What should I do?

Answer (score -2):

It's not something you can do on your browser, but I suggest using **wireshark**

You can see raw packets, and see HTTP request/ response.

good luck then!